# Where can I find Apple's iBooks formatting guide?

Tags: publishing, apple-books

I made a decision not to sign up for Apple's iBooks publishers' account (mainly because I don't own a Mac and use a Linux box most of the time -- also I don't want to buy ISBN numbers for my ebooks when selling them).  However, I would likely be uploading content to the Apple store via Smashwords.

How can I find out the latest formatting requirements and CSS support for Apple's iBooks?

Unlike Amazon, for some reason, Apple doesn't make this information available anywhere.  Can you recommend a good online resource for preparing your content for iBooks?

I can follow the Smashwords formatting requirements (and I have an iPad and iPhone to test things on), but some store/device specific information might make it easier to figure things out with.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need an ISBN if you want to upload your Smashword publication to the apple store? https://www.smashwords.com/about/supportfaq#apple

Comment: Anthon, wow, thanks for this information! What a mess -- is Apple conspiring with Bowker? This is something Smashwords should have taken care of....

Comment: Update: Smashwords provides free ISBNs, so that's not an issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can get a PDF of the iBooks Asset Guide from their site: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iBooksAssetGuide5.1Revision2.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Newest version (as of 8/2/2016) [v5.2.5](https://help.apple.com/itc/booksassetguide/) is on itunes connect.

- [iBooks Asset Guide 5.2.5](https://help.apple.com/itc/booksassetguide/)
- [iBooks Store Formatting Guidelines](https://help.apple.com/itc/ibooksstoreformatting/)

Tried editing the url from @Tom's answer and found this:

https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iBooksAssetGuide5.2.pdf